# Highcharts zoom issue when panning reversed xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using the [Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) library, I'm setting up charts with zooming/panning features.

If I create a `type: 'datetime'` xAxis and use `reversed: true`, I run into issues when trying to pan. It will immediately zoom all the way in whether I'm currently zoomed or not.

If I remove the **reversed** property, this issue does not occur. Has anyone else experienced this problem, or know where to look to fix it?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akehpzq4/) to display the issue. Use the **Shift key** to pan.

-

I've tried not using the **reversed** flag and sorting the data myself, but Highcharts throws an error if dates are not ascending it seems.

Comment: I reported the bug here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5997

Comment: This is indeed a bug with Highcharts after all. Thanks @morganfree , the issue is now being worked on. A partial fix has been posted in your issue thread, and I've responded to it with additional fixes that now allow a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments of the question, this is actually a bug with Highcharts.
The panning feature was not handling the `setExtremes(...)` function call properly when dealing with a reversed xAxis.

A bug was posted here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5997, which now include some commits with a fix (which I have tested myself).

And since then a suggested fix has been submitted for the [next Highcharts milestone](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/milestone/22).